# Error al obtener el ultimo valor de un jtable

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando obtener todos los valores de una fila de Jtable pero al seleccionar cualquier fila me manda por consola una excepcion de que no existe la ultima columna, en este caso yo intento obtener del jtable el numero de telefono y pasarlo a textfield, pero no me lo carga.

espero que me puedan ayudar y dejo el codigo que estoy usando:

```
 private void jtProductosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Conexion objCon = new Conexion();
            Connection conn = objCon.getConexion();

            int Fila = jtProductos.getSelectedRow();
            String nombre = jtProductos.getValueAt(Fila, 0).toString();

            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT nombre, contraseña, matricula, carrera, numerotelf FROM cliente WHERE nombre=?");

            ps.setString(1, nombre);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));
                txtContra.setText(rs.getString("Contraseña"));
                txtMatricula.setText(rs.getString("Matricula"));
                txtCarrera.setText(rs.getString("Carrera"));
                txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("Telefono"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

Comment: He notado que en la consulta tienes "numerotelf" y en el ResultSet en el momento que obtienes el valor colocas del campo tienes "Telefono" ?? puede que este sea el problema...

Comment: Y si es asi, debido a que es eso? si en mi jtable lo coloque en una columna llamada "Telefono"?

Comment: @JossRamirez en realidad debes revisar que los nombres de columnas usados sean los que definiste en tu tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Las columnas que defines en tu Query y las que defines al obtener los resultados del resultset son las que se tienen en tu tabla, te sugiero revises los nombre correctos:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Nombre, Contraseña, Matricula, Carrera, Telefono FROM cliente WHERE nombre=?");
...
...

         while (rs.next()) {
            txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("Nombre"));
            txtContra.setText(rs.getString("Contraseña"));
            txtMatricula.setText(rs.getString("Matricula"));
            txtCarrera.setText(rs.getString("Carrera"));
            txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("Telefono"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría usar el método .getString(int i) en lugar del .getString(String string) para ahorrarte estar revisando los nombres de tus columnas, sólo cuidar el índice de la columna (que es algo más rápido de checar), y te quedaría así:

```
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT nombre, contraseña, matricula, carrera, numerotelf FROM cliente WHERE nombre=?");

        ps.setString(1, nombre);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            txtNombre.setText(rs.getString(1));
            txtContra.setText(rs.getString(2));
            txtMatricula.setText(rs.getString(3));
            txtCarrera.setText(rs.getString(4));
            txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString(5));

        }
```

Saludos